# cannot get visual studio connected to mac

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-mac

I've tried to get Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition) working with a Mac to create a Mobile app iOS and Android. Unfortunatly I'm struggling the whole day wit this combination.

My current issue, which I cannot solve myself is the following error in Visual Studio on Windows:

```
An unexpected error occurred while checking the SSH configuration of '192.168.178.74'
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

I tried to change the MAc Address of the virtual machin to get a new IP Adress, without success

my setup:

- Visual Studio 2019 Comunity with Xamarin
- Mac OS Catalina in VM Ware on same machine than Windows 10
- XCode 11.3.1
- Visual Studio for Mac Community 8.4.8 (build 2)

Btw. I forgot to mention, that it is possible to log in to the Mac via ssh from Windows.

Comment: Try forgetting the machine in the dialog in VS for Windows. Otherwise try connecting manually.

Comment: There is no machine listed in the Dialog in VS, because it could never successfully complete connection to the mac.

Comment: Make sure the version of VS and Xcode are up to date . If the issue still exists , you could post it to VS support forums . **Help** -> **Send Feedback** -> **Report a problem**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with Visual Studio on Windows.
Microsoft seems to be aware of this and working on a solution.

Details: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/928605/an-error-occurred-while-generating-the-ssh-keys-pl.html

Update:
Microsoft just recently released version 16.5.2 of Visual Studio.
That released (non-preview) version fixed the issue for me ;-)

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, which will help more people.

Answer (score 19):

My fix to this issue was to delete the hosts.key file in this directory

%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\MonoTouch

Comment: after deleting hosts.key I#m getting this error when I try to connect to the Mac: An error occurred while generating the SSH keys. Please check that the environment is properly configured. Details: cat: /Users/thowa/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/Keys/1e342509-a199-4709-9d58-6d81a86ed129: No such file or directory

Comment: It works for my!
Try this options first

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this working. It seems that running `chmod og-w "$HOME"` on the MacOS device fixed it for me.

*However*,  I'm not 100% sure that was the only step because I've been debugging this for hours, so everything I did might be unnecessary, but if the above doesn't work alone, here is everything I did:

1. Followed steps from https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7882#issuecomment-604330852 to copy old scp (again, don't know if this was necessary)
2. Restart both machines just so you're sure you have a clean slate.
3. On the PC, delete *contents* of `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\MonoTouch` directory (leave the directory itself)
4. On the Mac, clear contents of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file
5. On the Mac, delete `~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA` directory
6. On the Mac, run `chmod og-w "$HOME"`
7. On the PC, start Visual Studio and try to connect

Comment: Deleting contents of %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\MonoTouch did the trick for me

Comment: Step 2 to 7 helped me. Step 1 i have skiped.

Answer (score 3):

I had not Monotouch folder, so I created it manually and run VS using Administrator privileges. This solved my problem.

Comment: i just created the MonoTouch directory via Explorer

Answer (score 0):

I found this error happened on VS 16.5.2 and after updating to 16.5.3 today it fixed the issue.

Comment: That is strange, what version of Mac OS do you use?

Comment: The latest Mac OS Catalina.